# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

this Struct is work in swift 2

I have a Swift 3 struct like this.

```
let tempContacts =  NSMutableArray()
let arrayOfArray =  NSMutableArray()
```

I have encode The Person Object in this for loop

```
    for person in tempContacts as! [Person] {

        let encodedObject: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: person) as Data
        arrayOfArray.add(encodedObject)

    }
```

I have decode the data in this for loop

```
let tempContacts2 = NSMutableArray()
   for data in arrayOfArray {

        let person: Person = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data) as! Person
        tempContacts2.add(person)   

    }
```

but unarchiveObject is always return nil value

Comment: Does your `Person` object conform to the `NSCoding` protocol?

Comment: yes i have used NScoding protocol in my Person class

Comment: Why do you use in **Swift !** a completely unrelated type like `NSMutableArray` rather than a Swift `Array` with the actual type `[Person]` in the decode part? You're throwing away the type information which is one of Swift's essential semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your model class should conform to the NSCoder protocol. The rest is really simple, there's no need to store the archived results for each object in an array, you can pass the initial array directly to NSKeyedArchiver like this :

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name = ""

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    // NSCoder
    required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String else { return nil }
        self.init(name: name)
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
    }
}

let tempContacts = [Person(name: "John"), Person(name: "Mary")]

let encodedObjects = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: tempContacts)
let decodedObjects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedObjects)
```

As a side **note** : if NSCoder compliance is correctly implemented in your model class, you can of course use your way of archiving/unarchiving individual objects too. So your original code works too, with some minor adjustments:

```
for person in tempContacts {
    let encodedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: person)
    arrayOfArray.add(encodedObject)
}

var tempContacts2 = [Person]()
for data in arrayOfArray {
    let person: Person = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data) as! Person
    tempContacts2.append(person)
}
```

**Note 2**: if you absolutely wants to use `NSMutableArray`s that's possible too, just define `tempContacts` like this:

```
let tempContacts =  NSMutableArray(array: [Person(name: "John"), Person(name: "Mary")])
```

The rest is working without changes.

**Note 3**: The reason it used to work in Swift 2 and it's not working anymore in Swift 3 is that the signature for the NSCoder method `func encode(with coder:)` changed in Swift 3.

Comment: sorry i have tempContacts is not [Person] arrye used

Comment: but actually tempContacts is NSMutableArray()

Comment: let person: Person = Person(name: "John")

Comment: tempContact.add(person)

Comment: Yes it works with NSMutableArray too, just see my second note.

Comment: But do you have any particular reason to use `NSMutableArray` instead of Swift arrays ?

Comment: Yes, no problem you could use a `NSMutableArray` and define it anyway you like, of course.

Comment: @PatelAnkit: if this is solving your issue, please don't forget to accept my answer

Comment: let person: Person = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data) as! Person

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: i have check for loop data and print

Comment: data is print  but data is pass in  unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data) and out put  is nil

Comment: I ran the code above in a Playground and it works perfectly. Something else must be wrong in your code.

Comment: yes  you are right i have test your code in playgroung is completely work

Comment: but i have actually used same your code in my project

Comment: Personally, I would like to thank you for putting in the effort to write of this.